# Template plugin for blog posts?

Tags: plugins, templates, forms, page-template

can someone recommend a plugin to do the following?

My wordpress CMS has two types of users: administrator and editor, both of whom are not technologically savvy, so they need things to be super simple.

The administrator wants to be able to create a re-useable template in the CMS that editors can use for their posts.

As an example, an administrator can create a template along the lines of

```
Welcome to the ________.
We are hosting our event at __________.
Buy your tickets for ______ dollars.
```

The editor can then login to the CMS, create a new blog post and import the template above and fill out the 3 underlined areas.

We want things to be a little more complex by giving the administrator the ability to add images, styling, and fields to record form registrations (form submissions get recorded to wordpress database).

What wordpress plugin comes closes to achieving the above results?

Comment: Any progress? Was my answer helpful? Do you still miss something?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom post type `post_templates`. It should not be publicly queryable, and the admin only should be able to create or edit items.

In your post editor you could then add a TinyMCE button/dropdown to let the editor select a template. Here is a [very basic example plugin](https://gist.github.com/2405345) illustrating how to work with preselected post content:

```
/*
 * See wp-admin/includes/post.php function get_default_post_to_edit()
 * There are also the filters 'default_title' and 'default_excerpt'
 */
add_filter( 'default_content', 't5_preset_editor_content', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Fills the default content for post type 'post' if it is not empty.
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @param object $post
 * @return string
 */
function t5_preset_editor_content( $content, $post )
{
    if ( '' !== $content or 'post' !== $post->post_type )
    {
        return $content;
    }

    return 'This is the <em>default</em> content. You may customize it.';
}
```