# Preset categories in wordpress by GET-paremters

Tags: plugins, posts

I tried google and used #wordpress. 
Is there a way to preset categories for my new posts (post-new.php) via GET-parameters? If not how can I achieve this?

Comment: please leave a comment if you downvote. THANKS! - already reported myself as a dublicate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dublicate question. But I think my question + link will help some ppl out.

[How to add category to: 'wp-admin/post-new.php'?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77504/how-to-add-category-to-wp-admin-post-new-php)