# How can I implement an Article Wizard for non-existing URLs?

Tags: urls

I very much like [Wikipedia's feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_will_be_a_new_Site) to create an article from a yet non-existing URL as shown below:

[image]

I imagine the workflow to be like this:

1. Open URL of the site you wish to create
2. If logged in, a button allows you to create the page with exactly this URL slug by forwarding you to the WP-Admin
3. If not logged in, you would only see a 404 error.

How would I begin building a plugin for this?

Comment: as always, the answer to "can something be done " is in 95% of the case "yes". If you are interested in a more useful answer please edit the question and be much more specific about what is it that you are asking about.

Comment: Hi Mark, your feedback is appreciated! I updated my question. Is it better now?

Comment: I don't know, is the challenge here is basically to show a "create a page here" type of button when an admin gets to a 404? (if yes, it is at least an interesting idea). The problem if such idea is that content can not just be created at any url under normal conditions, so the requirement here might need to be restricted to valid url

Comment: @MarkKaplun I guess if you've already 404-ed then that validation has kind of been done for you already though.

Comment: well, you can always change the behavior of 404 to show some default page with a form to a logged in user instead of sending an actual 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow the url must make clear that this is an editable link. So you need a filter on `the_content` that checks if there are internal links that do not yet exist. Alternatively, if you let users determine which links are editable you need to check if the url's they give perhaps already exist. The filter should set a class on the link. Here's a function to determine if a slug already exists:

```
function the_slug_exists($post_name) {
        global $wpdb;
        if($wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = '" . $post_name . "'", 'ARRAY_A')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now you get a page with links, some of which have the class `editable`. You can bind a javascript function to this class, which prevents normal link behaviour. You could even use it to hide the link completely for users who are not logged in. Logged in users get a little popup thats asks them if they want to create the page for the link.

The 'yes' button in the popup does not lead people to the url. Rather it takes the slug and adds it as a query variable to the new posts page: `http://www.example.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?slug=yournewpostslug`.

In your `functions.php` you add an action to `wp_insert_post` to catch the query variable and use it to fill fields in the editor. Read more about that method [in @toscho 's anwer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77504/how-to-add-category-to-wp-admin-post-new-php). Beware that editors at this point may still change the slug, so you may want to remove that box in this case using [`remove_meta_box`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box)

Answer (score 2):

I'd put an is_user_logged_in conditional into my theme's 404.php. Then for logged in users show a form with the new slug as a hidden or uneditable field that creates a new page and redirects to the admin edit screen for that page.